# Creating a pdf in an TYPO3 extbase extension on saving a record

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I am wondering how I can generate a pdf in an extbase extension. What I wanting to do is the following: On saving a record in the backend also a pdf with the data of my record should be generated an saved in the fileadmin for instance.

I have found frontend solutions for generating pdfs with special fluid viewhelpers primarily, but I need it in the backend when the editor saves a record.

Are there any common solutions in extbase for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating PDFs has no common solution in TYPO3.
Alas you have the option to hook in most actions to use an additional library to generate a PDF of the data you are processing.

You could find more information [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Hooks/Index.html)